Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON checkout. Using stimulus on Ruby on Rails
basically I'm using stimulusjs in ruby ​​on rails to create an ecommerce, and I'm trying to assign the stripe to my application (remembering that the functionality is on the cart page), but basically it's giving an error in which my information is not being passed on json (even though I correctly configured JSON.stringify). The problem is on checkout(){} probably
enter image description here
enter image description here
I've already tried changing the way to change files to json. Instead of using JSON.stringify, I tried passing the json information to my promises as response.json(), I have already reviewed my route but it is configured correctly, but nothing seems to be out of the ordinary.
cart_controller.js
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"

// Connects to data-controller="cart"
export default class extends Controller {
  initialize() {

    console.log("cart controller initialized")
    const cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart"))
    if (!cart) {
      return
    }

    let total = 0
    for (let i=0; i < cart.length; i++) {
      const item = cart[i]
      total += item.price * item.quantity
      const div = document.createElement("div")
      div.classList.add("mt-2")
      div.innerText = `Item: ${item.name} - $${item.price/100.0} - Size: ${item.size} - Quantity: ${item.quantity}`
      const deleteButton = document.createElement("button")
      deleteButton.innerText = "Remove"
      console.log("item.id: ", item.id)
      deleteButton.value = JSON.stringify({id: item.id, size: item.size})
      deleteButton.classList.add("bg-gray-500", "rounded", "text-white", "px-2", "py-1", "ml-2")
      deleteButton.addEventListener("click", this.removeFromCart)
      div.appendChild(deleteButton)
      this.element.prepend(div)
    }

    const totalEl = document.createElement("div")
    totalEl.innerText= `Total: $${total/100.0}`
    let totalContainer = document.getElementById("total")
    totalContainer.appendChild(totalEl)
  }

  clear() {
    localStorage.removeItem("cart")
    window.location.reload()
  }

  removeFromCart(event) {
    const cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart"))
    const values = JSON.parse(event.target.value)
    const {id, size} = values
    const index = cart.findIndex(item => item.id === id && item.size === size)
    if (index >= 0) {
      cart.splice(index, 1)
    }
    localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(cart))
    window.location.reload()
  }

  checkout() {
    const cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart"))
    const payload = {
      authenticity_token: "",
      cart: cart
    }

    const csrfToken = document.querySelector("[name='csrf-token']").content

    fetch("/checkout", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "X-CSRF-Token": csrfToken
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(payload)
    }).then(response => {
        if (response.ok) {
          response.json().then(body => {
            window.location.href = body.url
          })
        } else {
          response.json().then(body => {
            const errorEl = document.createElement("div")
            errorEl.innerText = `There was an error processing your order. ${body.error}`
            let errorContainer = document.getElementById("errorContainer")
            errorContainer.appendChild(errorEl)
          })
        }
      })
  }

}

checkouts_controller.rb
class CheckoutsController < ApplicationController
    def create
      stripe_secret_key = Rails.application.credentials.dig(:stripe, :secret_key)
      Stripe.api_key = stripe_secret_key
      cart = params[:cart]
      line_items = cart.map do |item|
        product = Product.find(item["id"])
        product_stock = product.stocks.find{ |ps| ps.size == item["size"] }
  
        if product_stock.amount < item["quantity"].to_i
          render json: { error: "Not enough stock for #{product.name} in size #{item["size"]}. Only #{product_stock.amount} left." }, status: 400
          return
        end
  
        { 
          quantity: item["quantity"].to_i,
          price_data: { 
            product_data: {
              name: item["name"],
              metadata: { product_id: product.id, size: item["size"], product_stock_id: product_stock.id }
            },
            currency: "usd",
            unit_amount: item["price"].to_i
          }
        } 
      end
  
      puts "line_items: #{line_items}"
  
      session = Stripe::Checkout::Session.create(
        mode: "payment",
        line_items: line_items,
        success_url: "http://localhost:3000/success",
        cancel_url: "http://localhost:3000/cancel",
        shipping_address_collection: { 
          allowed_countries: ['US', 'CA']
        }
      )
  
      render json: { url: session.url }
    end
  
    def success
      render :success
    end
  
    def cancel
      render :cancel
    end
  end

route.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :admin do
    resources :orders
    resources :products do
      resources :stocks
    end
    resources :categories
  end
  devise_for :admins
  # Define your application routes per the DSL in https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

  # Reveal health status on /up that returns 200 if the app boots with no exceptions, otherwise 500.
  # Can be used by load balancers and uptime monitors to verify that the app is live.
  get "up" => "rails/health#show", as: :rails_health_check

  # Defines the root path route ("/")
  root "home#index"

  authenticated :admin_user do
    root to: "admin#index", as: :admin_root
  end

  resources :categories, only: [:show]
  resources :products, only: [:show]

  get "admin" => "admin#index"
  get "cart" => "carts#show"
  post "checkout" => "checkouts#create"
  get "success" => "checkouts#success"
  get "cancel" => "checkouts#cancel"
end

view carts
<div class="min-h-screen">
  <h1>Cart Page</h1>
  <div id="errorContainer"></div>
  <div data-controller="cart">
    <div class="mt-4 font-medium" id="total"></div>
    <button class="mt-4 py-2 px-4 bg-gray-500 hover:bg-gray-600 rounded text-white" data-action="click->cart#checkout">Checkout</button>
    <button class="py-2 px-4 bg-gray-500 hover:bg-gray-600 rounded text-white" data-action="click->cart#clear">Clear Cart</button>
  </div>
</div>


Look at the raw response in the Network panel, you might see an error message embedded in HTML. That may help identify where the problem is.
